# NodeJS: write to file responses of multiple GET requests in order

Tags: node.js, json, get, writefile, appendfile

I have an array of urls, and I need to call each one of them and write the response to file in a valid JSON in order. E.g., `[resp1, resp2, resp3,...]`.
However, in the code below I get the responses written to file in random orders. E.g., `[resp3]resp1,resp2,`. How can I prevent that from happening within a foreach with many of urls (so that I cannot next them manually)?

```
fs.writeFile('my_file.json', "[", (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
});
urls.forEach((url, index) => {
  https.get(url, (resp) => {
    let data = '';
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });
    resp.on('end', () => {
      let output = data;
      (index == urls.length) ? output += ']' : output += ',' 
      fs.appendFileSync('my_file.json', output, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
    });
  }).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error: " + err.message);
  });
});
```

Comment: How about saving the response data in a variable in the first step, in the second step iterate again with urls.forEach and do fs.appendFilesSyn in the 2nd loop

Comment: @MasterOfDesaster the problem with that solution would be that it would require too much memory. The response data is large, and the urls can be quite big.

Answer (score 1):

Consider mapping each request to a Promise and then use `Promise.all` instead, and then write to the file only *once*:

```
const urlProms = urls.map(url => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  https.get(url, (resp) => {
    let data = '';
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });
    resp.on('end', () => resolve(data));
  })
  .on('error', reject);
}));
Promise.all(urlProms)
  .then((dataArr) => {
    fs.writeFile('my_file.json', JSON.stringify(dataArr), (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // handle errors
  });
```

Manually constructing/concatenating JSON strings is rarely a good idea. If you *had* to do it manually, use `async`/`await` to wait for each iteration in order, to make sure everything gets inserted in the proper order, and that overlapping requests don't take up too much memory:

```
const getData = url => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  https.get(url, (resp) => {
    let data = '';
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });
    resp.on('end', () => resolve(data));
  })
  .on('error', reject);
});
(async () => {
  fs.writeFileSync('my_file.json', '[', (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
  for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    const data = await getData(urls[i]);
    fs.appendFileSync('my_file.json', data, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
  }
  fs.appendFileSync('my_file.json', ']', (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
})();
```

Comment: the reason of writing that gradually was that the size of the response and the length of the url array can be very big, and you can run out of memory, although your approach would work in other scenarios.

Comment: See edit, you can `await` each iteration to make sure they go in the right order, and that not too much memory is used